# reference of eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
// Original code which has bug.
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (!createLineupPanel.activeSelf) return;
    GameObject selectedObject = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject;
    if (selectedObject.name == CARDSLOTPANEL)
    {
        CardInfo cardInfo = selectedObject.transform.parent.Find("Card").GetComponent<CardInfo>();
        if (cardInfo.GetCardType() == "Tactic") // Same tactic should warn.
            lineupBuilder.AddTactic(cardInfo);
        else
        {
            string cardName = cardInfo.GetCardName();
            foreach (Vector2 loc in boardInfo.typeLocations[cardInfo.GetCardType()])
            {
                string oldLocPieceName = boardInfo.locations[loc];
                if ((cardName.StartsWith("Standard ") && !oldLocPieceName.StartsWith("Standard ")) ||
                    (!cardName.StartsWith("Standard ") && oldLocPieceName.StartsWith("Standard ")) ||
                    (cardInfo.GetCardType() == "General" && cardName != oldLocPieceName))
                {
                    lineupBuilder.AddPiece(cardInfo, loc);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// My bad solution.
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (!createLineupPanel.activeSelf) return;
    GameObject selectedObject = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject;
    if (selectedObject.name == CARDSLOTPANEL)
    {
        CardInfo cardInfo = selectedObject.transform.parent.Find("Card").GetComponent<CardInfo>();
        if (cardInfo.GetCardType() == "Tactic") 
            lineupBuilder.AddTactic(cardInfo);
        else
        {
            // The "else" part is the part that matters.
            dragCard = Instantiate(selectedObject.transform.parent.Find("Card").gameObject, parentCanvas.transform);
            string cardName = cardInfo.GetCardName();
            foreach (Vector2 loc in boardInfo.typeLocations[cardInfo.GetCardType()])
            {
                string oldLocPieceName = boardInfo.locations[loc];
                if ((cardName.StartsWith("Standard ") && !oldLocPieceName.StartsWith("Standard ")) ||
                    (!cardName.StartsWith("Standard ") && oldLocPieceName.StartsWith("Standard ")) ||
                    (cardInfo.GetCardType() == "General" && cardName != oldLocPieceName))
                {
                    dragCard.GetComponent<CardInfo>().SetAttributes(cardInfo);
                    lineupBuilder.AddPiece(dragCard.GetComponent<CardInfo>(), loc);
                    break;
                }
            }
            Destroy(dragCard);
        }            
    }
}
```

I am currently implementing a function that if you click on a card in the collection the card will be removed from the collection and be added to the card slot. And the problem is the selectedObject, which refers to  eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject. Since I remove that card from collection, the selectedObject is changed automatically to the next card (the next card moves to the current card location) and the cardInfo is consequently changed to the next card's cardInfo. So the card added to the card slot actually becomes the next card instead of the original card.

The only solution I can think of is to create a copy of selectedObject then set it with old cardInfo and then destroy it, which is shown in my code posted. Is there a better way or an easier way to do this? My solution is seems complicated.

If I directly use `lineupBuilder.AddPiece(selectedObject.GetComponent<CardInfo>(), loc)` instead of creating a copy, that's not going to work, because the object that selectedObject refers to has changed.

Comment: You're caching the reference before it changes, that makes sense, and if like you say it works then stick with it.

Comment: @Lece But this seems complicated. I don't want to get the cardinfo by creating a new object and then assigning old attributes to it and then reading the values and destroying it. I think there should be an easy copy way. I tried writing a copy function for the cardInfo but I always get a NullReference.

Comment: Understood, but this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)? Are you looking to fix the original problem or simply looking to improve the working code that you've posted? :)

Comment: @Lece I hope to fix the problem in a better way,

Comment: @Lece I have updated my original code. Could you please check it out?